# How to mock private function of a class using jasmine test framework

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine2.0

I am trying to mock private function of my class. I am already testing my private method using testEmployee.__private.getStatus(). The issue I am facing is the mocking of private function getStatus. I want to test processSalary() with different status code return by mocked getStatus function.

Here is my code.

```js
var Employee = function() { 
    . . . . . // other private members
 
    function getStatus() {
        . . . . // other business logic
        return call_external_service_for_status(employeeData);
    };
    
    . . . .  //other private functions
    
         
    //public methods
    this.processSalary = function(){
        var employeeStatus = getStatus()
        if(employeeStatus === 1){
           . . . 
        }
        else if(employeeStatus === 2)
        {
          . . . . . 
        }
        . . . . . .  // other conditional statements
     };
     
     this.__private = {
        getStatus: getStatus
        . . . . //other private functions
     }  
}; 

describe("Employee salary", function() {
    it("process Employee salary with status 1", function() {
        var testEmployee = new Employee();
        // want to mock private function to return status as 1
        testEmployee.processSalary();
        expect(testPerson.getStatus).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...

//public methods
this.processSalary = function(){
    var employeeStatus = getStatus() // <<<<<<<< should this be
                                     // this.__private.getStatus() ?
    if(employeeStatus === 1){
       . . . 
    }
    else if(employeeStatus === 2)
    {
      . . . . . 
    }
    . . . . . .  // other conditional statements
 };

...

describe("Employee salary", function() {
    it("process Employee salary with status 1", function() {
        var testEmployee = new Employee();
        // want to mock private function to return status as 1
        // <<<<<<<<< then here you can redefine the "private" 
        // member of the class
        testEmployee.__private.getStatus = function() {
           console.log("I'm doing new things");
        }
        testEmployee.processSalary();
        expect(testPerson.getStatus).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Functions declared as you declared them in the "other private functions" section will not be changeable if they're used without reference to their parent class inside a public method.

You could refer to this.__private.getStatus in the public method, but you exchange privacy for the convenience of being able to redefine the property during testing.

The question this points to is how to design a class system that will behave the way you expect! https://philipwalton.com/articles/implementing-private-and-protected-members-in-javascript/ < some pretty good reading on the subject.

...

All that said, if the function can't be tested, it might be a good case for a refactor.